# Tekton Task not Expanding Parameters (OpenShift)

Tags: openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am unable to pass parameters to a Tekton task via the CLI or via TaskRun YAML.

Task file

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-test
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
spec:
  params:
    - name: var
      type: string
  steps:
    - env:
        - name: VAR
          value: $(params.var)
      image: ubuntu
      name: ''
      resources: {}
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        echo "Hello from Bash $VAR!"
```

TaskRun file

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TaskRun
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-test-with-parameters
spec:
  taskRef:
    name: ubuntu-test
  params:
    - name: var
      value:
        - "John"
```

Regardless if I apply the TaskRun via the YAML file above or run `tkn task start --showlog ubuntu-test -p var=John` I receive the following output:

```
[unnamed-0] Hello from Bash $(params.var)!
```

Environment Info

```
PS > tkn version
Client version: 0.16.0
Pipeline version: v0.10.1
Triggers version: v0.11.2
Dashboard version: v0.14.0

PS > oc version
Client Version: 4.6.16
Server Version: 4.6.15
Kubernetes Version: v1.19.0+1833054
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the v10.1.1 pipeline release does not support the `v1beta1` API version. I had followed an outdated tutorial [here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/07/19/getting-started-with-tekton-on-red-hat-openshift/) that installs an outdated version of Pipelines via an [improperly tagged "latest" release](https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/latest/release.yaml.).

If anyone comes across a similar issue, make sure your versions match the expected latest version of the [GitHub release](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/releases).